# Google sign-in button not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, oauth, google-api-js-client

Repro: Go to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in and click on the Sign In button.

I'm getting a blank popup and this error in Chrome 68:
[image]

I thought it was an ad blocker issue so i created a new chrome profile and managed to get past the blank screen, but when i entered my email and tried to proceed this happened:
[image]

Works fine for Firefox 62 and Edge 42 and Chrome 68 on my android device...

Anyone experiencing this too or knows a workaround?